# MySQL change type while trigger before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, aes

I want MySQL to encrypt data with AES automatically, so that I don't have do do it in the application layer. First question: Is this even possible?
I tried that simple approach:

Table:

```
measurement
id INT
value VARBINARY(50)
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `openeHealth`.`measurement_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `measurement` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-ecb';
    DECLARE vKey = RANDOM_BYTES(256);
    SET NEW.value HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(value, vKey));
END
```

It's my first try to use triggers so maybe it's a simple failure or maybe MySQL doesn't support something like this.

My testinsert has a Double value as 'value'.

And yes, I am aware of the fact that I need to store my random key somewhere. So maybe someone has an idea how to update another table due "insert before" to?

Thanks a lot

Error Message:

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.., 1)' at line 1
SQL Code:
    INSERT INTO `openeHealth`.`measurement` (`id`, `owner_id`, `type_id`, `value`, `device_id`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, ..., 1)
```

Generated Code of MySQL Workbench:

```
START TRANSACTION;
USE `openeHealth`;
INSERT INTO `openeHealth`.`measurement` (`id`, `owner_id`, `type_id`, `value`, `device_id`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, ..., 1);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: 1) if you encrypt data this way, it is not going to be searchable. Are you sure this is what you want? 2) Pls provide the exact error message or unexpected behaviour you encountered while using your own code.

Comment: Yes, I don't want the value to be searchable just the id of the value should be in plaintext. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

> [14.6.3 DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html)
>
> ...
>
> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `measurement`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `measurement`(
    ->   `id` INT,
    ->   `value` VARBINARY(50)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `measurement_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `measurement`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `SESSION_block_encryption_mode` VARCHAR(33) DEFAULT @@SESSION.`block_encryption_mode`;
    ->   -- SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-ecb';
    ->   -- DECLARE vKey = RANDOM_BYTES(256);
    -> 
    ->   SET @@SESSION.`block_encryption_mode` := 'aes-256-ecb';
    -> 
    ->   -- SET NEW.value HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(value, vKey));
    ->   SET NEW.`value` := HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(NEW.`value`, RANDOM_BYTES(256)));
    ->   SET @@SESSION.`block_encryption_mode` := `SESSION_block_encryption_mode`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> INSERT INTO `measurement`
    ->   (`id`, `value`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (1, 'myKey');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `value`
    -> FROM
    ->   `measurement`;
+------+----------------------------------+
| id   | value                            |
+------+----------------------------------+
|    1 | 10293FC4F42FC7BAAA91C94EFF004315 |
+------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Timo would you please mark this with the Green checkmark as Accepted if you agree.